# Why is my core file not overwritten by GDB?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gdb, coredump, filemtime

On Ubuntu 12.04, open a new text file and write:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    abort();
    return 0;
}
```

Now run:

```
g++ yourfile.cpp
```

Then run the executable, which will core dump:

```
./a.out
```

Now check the mtime of the file:

```
-rw-r----- 1 xxxxx xxxxx 228K 2012-10-01 19:20:20.752136399 -0500 core
```

Now run the executable again:

```
./a.out
```

Now check the mtime again:

```
-rw-r----- 1 xxxxx xxxxx 228K 2012-10-01 19:20:20.752136399 -0500 core
```

It's the same! Why doesn't a fresh core dump overwrite the old one? When rebuilding this causes gdb to complain the core is older than the executable.

Just to be sure it wasn't a permissions problem, I tried this in a fresh directory in /tmp and ran `chmod -R 777 **/*` inside. Running the executable twice still didn't produce a new core O_o Also, `ulimit -c` reports 800000000, more than enough for a core this size.

I also tried running a clean bash with `env - bash --noprofile --norc` and still running the binary doesn't update the mtime of the core unless I delete it first.

Comment: What are the permissions on `a.out`?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: -rwxrwxr-x 1 xxxxx xxxxx 141K Sep 30 22:06 a.out*

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: I've now updated the question so it's easily reproducible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you refer to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apport/+bug/160999 this is a bug in Ubuntu using `O_EXCL` to open the file, preventing it from overwriting an existing core.

Comment: Bug in apport to be specific. STILL not fixed in 2016. It makes debugging sessions orders of magnitude more frustrating.

Answer (score 2):

The [core(5)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man5/core.5.html) man page lists certain conditions under which a `core` file is not [re-]written. You probably meet one of those conditions. Please read carefully that man page.

Comment: All of those conditions prevent writing, but not rewriting. I don't see how just rm'ing the file would change any of the situations they list... if I can make the file I obviously have permissions, I'm not making hard links to the core so there can't be more than one, file system isn't full, directory obviously exists, since the core is the same size as before can't be ulimits, have to have read permission for the binary otherwise how am I running, and it's not setuid...

Comment: I've updated my post with details on eliminated possibilities.

Comment: OK, and now I have a reproducible example ;)